Create and get data from tables with many-to-many relation on prisma
My schema looks like this:
model Product {
  id          String   @id @default(uuid())
  title       String   @db.VarChar(255)
  value       Float
  description String
  quantity    Int
  companyId   String
  imgUrl      String?
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  Company         Company           @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id])
  sales           Sale[]
  ProductsOnSales ProductsOnSales[]
}

model Sale {
  id         String    @id @default(uuid())
  client     String
  company_id String
  products   Product[]

  Company         Company           @relation(fields: [company_id], references: [id])
  ProductsOnSales ProductsOnSales[]
}

model ProductsOnSales {
  id         String @id @unique @default(uuid())
  product_id String
  sale_id    String

  Product Product @relation(fields: [product_id], references: [id])
  Sale    Sale    @relation(fields: [sale_id], references: [id])

  @@map("productsOnSales")
}

I created two routes, one to create new sales, and one to get sales, my repository looks like this:
 public async getSales(companyId: string): Promise<Sale[]> {
    const sales = await this.db.findMany({
      where: {
        company_id: companyId,
      },
      include: {
        products: true,
      },
    });

    return sales;
  }

  public async createSale({
    client,
    companyId,
    products,
  }: SalesPayload): Promise<void> {
    await this.db.create({
      data: {
        client,
        company_id: companyId,
        ProductsOnSales: {
          createMany: {
            data: products.map((product) => ({
              product_id: product,
            })),
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }

My problem is, its creating the sales, and relating them on my productsOnSales table, but when I retrieve data from a sale, it does not bring me any products, it just returns an empty array. Could anyone help me?
This is the return i got:
[
    {
        "id": "b99d1a91-3b50-42a4-9abc-b6f38d11423e",
        "client": "Test Company LTDA",
        "company_id": "580f9ab9-c52d-4a99-a136-6a87cbae652f",
        "products": []
    }
]


Was there possibly a mistake in cleaning up your example code? You write that your query is this.db.findMany()when it should be db.<model>.findMany(); in this case, it would mean e.g. this.db.sales.findMany(..)
